# how to view trace statments on ipad (adobe air)

Tags: ipad, debugging, air, adobe, trace

What's the proper adobe-air way to tail/log trace statements against my ipad (physical device)?  I'm looking for something analogous to android's "adb logcat".

I tried poking around the ADL examples but my impression is that ADL is only intended to work with virtual devices.

AIR_SDK version 4.6.0.23201